# Only first element is visible in Dynamic Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script, html-select, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to have a dependent Dropdown list, Districts based on the value of selected State. But my code is rendering only the first element of the dynamic dropdown list.

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
<select id="nativeDistr">
    <option value="" disabled selected>
        Native District
    </option>
</select>
<label>Destination District</label>
```

;

> **Appscript Code Snippet.**

```
function getDistricts(state) {
Logger.log("Selected State=" + state);
var fileName = "states-and-districts.json";
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
try {
    if (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
        var json = JSON.parse(content).states_districts;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if (json[i]["state"] === state) {
                var districts = json[i]["districts"];
            }
        }
    }
    var optList = generateOptions(districts);
    Logger.log(optList);
    return optList;
} catch (err) {
    return "Error getting data";
}
```

}

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("nativeState").addEventListener("change", getDistr);

function getDistr() {
    var state = document.getElementById("nativeState").value;
    console.log("state scriptt:" + state);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatedistricts).getDistricts(state);
}

function updatedistricts(districts) {
    console.log("From districts:" + districts);
    var nativeDistr = document.getElementById("nativeDistr");
    nativeDistr.innerHTML = districts;
    M.updateTextFields();
} // When user selects the state the valuee off the state should get registered for district search
```

> Blockquote

Durin execution I am getting the complete list of dynamic dropdown but while rendering the page only the first element is getting displayed.

> Blockquote

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[M.updateTextFields()](https://materializecss.com/select.html) do not update dynamic dropdown, it updates the text fields. So there is a need to store a global reference to materialize select box to initialize it, post that there is a need to destroy that instance, and then reinitialize the select box again.

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll("select");
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        });
 document.getElementById("nativeState").addEventListener("change", getDistr);

function getDistr() {
   var state = document.getElementById("nativeState").value;       
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatedistricts).getDistricts(state);

}

function updatedistricts(distrList){         
    nativeDistr.innerHTML  = distrList;
    var subcatSelectElem = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    var subcatSelectInstance = M.FormSelect.init(subcatSelectElem, {});

}
```

[Credit for soln.: Chicago Computer Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc8-vJ5r3e0&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l&index=5)